# Closing a mercurial branch creates a new head?

Tags: linux, version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to close an old branch that is no longer used but every time I do the close command on this branch it says a new head is created. Other branches do not have this issue. Does anyone know what my issue could be?

```
jchan@jchan-Z170N:~/eclipse-workspace/filtec-src/src$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.7.3)
...
jchan@jchan-Z170N:~/eclipse-workspace/filtec-src/src$ hg update -r version1.5.11 -C
1367 files updated, 0 files merged, 6050 files removed, 0 files unresolved
jchan@jchan-Z170N:~/eclipse-workspace/filtec-src/src$ hg commit --close-branch -m "closing legacy branch"
created new head
```

when i query the list of branches again this branch keeps showing up:

hg branches
...
version1.5.11

Why is this? I am using mercurial command line on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Closing a branch creates a new commit.

Comment: @zerkms what about keeping this branch even if never use it again. Anything bad will be caused? Hah, that is what I did so far.

Comment: Closing a branch just hides it from `hg branches` and other commands. Practically, it won't harm indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Found that I was able to use the tortoise Hg tool "thg" to search and find all the head commits on the miss behaving branch and then merge them all together. After merging all these similar heads together I was able to close the final head and now this branch no longer comes up in the hg branches query.